# Perl Modification of non creatable array value attempted, subscript -1

Tags: arrays, perl, compare

I have a Perl-Script, which executes a recursive function. Within it compares two elements of a  2dimensional Array:

I call the routine with a 2D-Array "@data" and "0" as a starting value. First I load the parameters into a separate 2D-Array "@test"

Then I want to see, if the array contains only one Element --> Compare if the last Element == the first. And this is where the Error occurs: Modification of non creatable array value attempted, subscript -1.

> You tried to make an array value spring into existence, and the subscript was probably negative, even counting from end of the array backwards.

This didn't help me much...I'm pretty sure it has to do with the if-clause "$counter-1". But I don't know what, hope you guys can help me!

```
routine(@data,0);

sub routine {
    my @test #(2d-Array) 

    my $counter = $_[-1]

    for(my $c=0; $_[$c] ne $_[-1]; $c++){

        for (my $j=0; $j<13;$j++){    #Each element has 13 other elements

            $test[$c][$j] = $_[$c][$j];

        }
    }
    if ($test[$counter-1][1] eq $test[-1][1]{

        $puffertime  = $test[$counter][4];

    }
    else{
        for (my $l=0; $l<=$counter;$l++){

            $puffertime+= $test[$l][4]

        }
    }    
}
#
#
#

if ($puffertime <90){

    if($test[$counter][8]==0){

        $counter++;
        routine(@test,$counter);
    }  


    else{ return (print"false");}

}
else{return (print "true");}
```

Weird thing is that I tried it out this morning, and it worked. After a short time of running he again came up with this error message. Might be that I didn't catch up a error constellation, which could happen by the dynamic database-entries.

Comment: Are you using last element of the array to store the number of elements? What's with `my $counter = $_[-1]` ?

Comment: @Arkadiy , he's passing counter as the 'second' argument of routine.

Comment: Im using the last element of test with[-1][1] which contains an unique ID to check if the array has only one element and then pass a value to $puffertime, which is important for the following code

Comment: You're not showing us your real code, nor even otherwise-working code that has just the problem you're encountering, so an answer that debugs your code is unlikely.  You can still get an answer that tells you how better to do things you'd like to do, but it'd be a better answer if `routine` had a real name and if we knew what it's intended to return.

Comment: I think your copy loop does not copy the last row of the array.
When `$c` is the last index, `$_[$c] ne $_[-1]` becomes false.

Comment: added the full code, and the routine really has ne name routine, cause its the only one in the script ^^ - already thx 4 the trouble ;)

Comment: It's not meant to copy the last row, because the last row is the counter, i just want the 2dimensional array!

Comment: it works! i just didnt pass the values right to the @data array so it called the function with an empty array...

Comment: this still isn't the real code; note the lack of semicolon after the @test and $counter declarations.  Please always copy and paste real running code (trimmed as much as possible while still demonstrating the problem if you want to make it easier to answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your `routine()` function would be easier to read if it starts off like this:

```
sub routine {
  my @data = @_;
  my $counter = pop(@data);
  my @test;

  for(my $c=0; $c <= $#data; $c++){
    for (my $j=0; $j<13;$j++){    #Each element has 13 other elements
      $test[$c][$j] = $data[$c][$j];
    }
  }
```

You can check to see if @data only has one element by doing `scalar(@data) == 1` or `$#data == 0`. From your code snippet, I do not see why you need to copy the data to passed to `routine()` to `@test`. Seems superfluous. You can just as well skip all this copying if you are not going to modify any of the data passed to your routine.
Your next code might look like this:

```
if ($#test == 0) {
  $puffertime = $test[0][4];
} else {
  for (my $l=0; $l <= $counter; $l++) {
    $puffertime += $test[$l][4];
  }
}
```

But if your global variable `$puffertime` was initialized to zero then you can replace this code with:

```
for (my $l=0; $l <= $counter; $l++) {
  $puffertime += $test[$l][4];
}
```